# How do I place image in shiny application that is called as a function?

Tags: r, shiny

The only method I'm aware of to embed images from package in shiny application requires the traditional shiny template i.e. app.R and requires images be placed in www/ folder

However, I have a traditional R package (not traditional shiny template), and one of it's many functions inside `R/` is a function to launch a shiny application. The function does some data preprocessing, specifies ui and server, then calls `runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))`.

I can of course provide an image url to the `src` argument, but the image will only display if user has internet access, and I'd like to include within the package itself so it will source image from package, not url. I've tried creating the www/ folder in package and specifying the image path for `src` argument with no luck...

How to setup image in R package directory so I can successfully source and not require an internet connection to view image? See reprex below of current approach that requires internet connection:

```
library(shiny)
launchShiny <- function(data){
  #example of some data preprocessing
  appdata <- as.data.frame(data)
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel(title = span(" ", tags$a(href = "#!", class = "brand-logo", tags$img(height = 100, width = 420, style = "padding-bottom: 0px", src = "https://i.ibb.co/d0btktV/why.png")), "")),
    dataTableOutput("mydata")
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session)
    output$mydata <- renderDataTable(
      appdata
    )
  
  runApp(
    shinyApp(ui, server)
  )
}
```

```
launchShiny(mtcars)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to pass a base64 string to the `src` argument:

```r
b64 <- base64enc::dataURI(file = "why.png", mime = "image/png")
tags$img(src = b64, ......)
```